# How to link shared library into another shared library depending on the target architecture?

Tags: android, c++, cmake, android-ndk

I want to link a precompiled shared library for different architectures on Android to my own jni shared library using CMake.
I am trying to do it using `target_link_libraries` command.
Here is my CMake file:

```
cmake_minimum_required(VERSION 3.4.1)

set(CMAKE_C_STANDARD 99)
set (CMAKE_CXX_STANDARD 11)

add_library( # Sets the name of the library.
             python-algo-jni

             # Sets the library as a shared library.
             SHARED

             # Provides a relative path to your source file(s).
             jni.cpp )

set_target_properties(python-algo-jni PROPERTIES LINKER_LANGUAGE CXX)
target_link_libraries(python-algo-jni libs/${ANDROID_ABI}/libpython3.5m.so)
```

When I try to build I get this error:

```
Execution failed for task ':calmnessscore:externalNativeBuildDebug'.
> Build command failed.
  Error while executing process /Users/mac/Library/Android/sdk/cmake/3.6.4111459/bin/cmake with arguments {--build /Users/mac/Projects/PythonAlgorithmAndroid/calmnessscore/.externalNativeBuild/cmake/debug/x86_64 --target python-algo-jni}
  [1/2] Building CXX object CMakeFiles/python-algo-jni.dir/jni.cpp.o
  [2/2] Linking CXX shared library /Users/mac/Projects/PythonAlgorithmAndroid/calmnessscore/build/intermediates/cmake/debug/obj/x86_64/libpython-algo-jni.so
  FAILED: : && /Users/mac/Library/Android/sdk/ndk-bundle/toolchains/llvm/prebuilt/darwin-x86_64/bin/clang++  --target=x86_64-none-linux-android --gcc-toolchain=/Users/mac/Library/Android/sdk/ndk-bundle/toolchains/x86_64-4.9/prebuilt/darwin-x86_64 --sysroot=/Users/mac/Library/Android/sdk/ndk-bundle/sysroot -fPIC -isystem /Users/mac/Library/Android/sdk/ndk-bundle/sysroot/usr/include/x86_64-linux-android -D__ANDROID_API__=21 -g -DANDROID -ffunction-sections -funwind-tables -fstack-protector-strong -no-canonical-prefixes -Wa,--noexecstack -Wformat -Werror=format-security   -O0 -fno-limit-debug-info  -Wl,--exclude-libs,libgcc.a --sysroot /Users/mac/Library/Android/sdk/ndk-bundle/platforms/android-21/arch-x86_64 -Wl,--build-id -Wl,--warn-shared-textrel -Wl,--fatal-warnings -Wl,--no-undefined -Wl,-z,noexecstack -Qunused-arguments -Wl,-z,relro -Wl,-z,now -shared -Wl,-soname,libpython-algo-jni.so -o /Users/mac/Projects/PythonAlgorithmAndroid/calmnessscore/build/intermediates/cmake/debug/obj/x86_64/libpython-algo-jni.so CMakeFiles/python-algo-jni.dir/jni.cpp.o  -llibs/x86_64/libpython3.5m.so -lm "/Users/mac/Library/Android/sdk/ndk-bundle/sources/cxx-stl/gnu-libstdc++/4.9/libs/x86_64/libgnustl_static.a" && :
  /Users/mac/Library/Android/sdk/ndk-bundle/toolchains/x86_64-4.9/prebuilt/darwin-x86_64/lib/gcc/x86_64-linux-android/4.9.x/../../../../x86_64-linux-android/bin/ld: error: cannot find -llibs/x86_64/libpython3.5m.so
  clang++: error: linker command failed with exit code 1 (use -v to see invocation)
  ninja: build stopped: subcommand failed.
```

But the library is there fo sure.

Comment: You must use curly braces for dereferencing a CMake variable, i.e. `${TARGET_ARCH_ABI}`

Comment: I modified the code and now it outputs another error

Comment: Try to locate the libpython3.5m.so by find_library.

Comment: To check whether it solves your problem first specify the complete path to your libpython3.5m.so in the `target_link_libraries` call.

Comment: @vre Oh. Yes it solved my problem, thank you. Now I am looking how to compile it with relative path.

Comment: CMake always wants absolute paths. You could specify `link_directories` but thats rather old style. I would recommend to use `find_package(PythonLibs 3.5)` and use the variables defined there.

Answer (score 0):

I found the solution: Just add `${CMAKE_CURRENT_SOURCE_DIR}/` to the lib path

`target_link_libraries(python-algo-jni     ${CMAKE_CURRENT_SOURCE_DIR}/libs/${ANDROID_ABI}/libpython3.5m.so)`